# jQuery Not Binding to Newly-Created <input> Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding

This is what I have:

```
<script language="javascript">
$('#click').one('click', function () {
   var html = '<input type="text" class="input-mini" id="new-input" />';
   $(this).parent().append(html);
});
$('#new-input').on('keyup', function (e) {
   alert('A key was pressed');
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert('Enter key pressed');
   }
});
</script>
```

At the recommendation of [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements), I found that I should use `on()` to bind dynamically created elements. What I want to happen is for an AJAX call to occur after the user presses the Enter key inside the `<input>` with ID `new-input`. However, nothing happens when any key is pressed at all.

What do I need to do in order to bind the `keyup` method to the newly-appended `<input>` element?

Thanks

Comment: Is "one" a typo in your first event handler?

Comment: No, it is not a typo.

Comment: Oh, it's an actual jQuery method, I was not aware...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on)

`.on()` does not always bind dynamically-created elements; it only does that if you pass a selector to listen inside of:

```
$('some container').on('click', '.new-input', function() { ... });
```

Also, IDs must be unique; you should use classes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used an ID because it was convenient in editor. My real code is much different and actually binds to a few different things to get to the keyup. I will accept the answer in 10 minutes, when it allows!

Answer (score 1):

At the time that the keyup binding is created, there won't be a matching element on the dom - try moving the second binding inside the callback for the first:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('#click').one('click', function () {
       var html = $('<input type="text" class="input-mini" />');

       html.on('keyup', function (e) {
           alert('A key was pressed');
           if (e.keyCode == 13) {
               alert('Enter key pressed');
           }
        });

       $(this).parent().append(html);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/qTd9c/

```
$('#click').one('click', function () {
    var html = '<input type="text" class="input-mini" id="new-input" />';
    $(this).parent().append(html);

    $('#new-input').on('keyup', function (e) {
        alert('A key was pressed');
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert('Enter key pressed');
        }
    });

});
```